# PDO Output to JSON formatting

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have a simple bit of PHP here:

```
$root="../../";
include $root . 'config/config.php';
require $root . 'vendor/autoload.php';

$list = "SELECT words FROM random_words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";

$list1 = $pdo->query($list)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$list2 = $pdo->query($list)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

I would like to loop through the results of `$list1` and output the random word, joined with the corresponding random word from `list2`, to end up with this type of JSON output

```
[{
  "id": 0,
  "random_combination": "scans.graduate"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "random_combination": "apricot.dudley"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "random_combination": "flushed.subscript"
}]
```

However, I am having trouble working out how I would achieve that.

I have been able to cobble something together like this:

```
$words = array();

for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {

    $un1 = $list1[$x];
    $un2 = $list2[$x];
    $un3 = $un1 . "." . $un2;

    $words['output']['id'][] = $x;
    $words['output']['random_combination'][] = $un3;

    $output = json_encode($words);

}

print_r($words);
```

With a print_r of $words returning:

```
Array
(
    [output] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

            [random_combination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => scans.graduate
                    [1] => apricot.dudley
                    [2] => flushed.subscript
                )

        )

)
```

However, that's not quite the same as the output I'd like to achieve, but I can't work out the logic to get what I'm after.

Comment: Try `$words['output'][]['id'] = $x;
    $words['output'][]['random_combination'] = $un3;` instead. And move the json_encode command to outside the loop, at the end

Comment: Why execute twice wouldn't `LIMIT 6` do the same thing?

Comment: It was to get two sets of random words... if it was all one list, I'd have to chop the list into two halves, and get e.g. the first word and join it with the first word from the 2nd half of the list of words, then increment by 1, and join the 2nd word from the 1st half with the 2nd word from the 2nd half...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you code more generic use `foreach` instead of `for`:

```
foreach ($list1 as $k => $v) {
    $words['output'][] = [
        'id' => $k,
        'random_combination' => $v . '.' . $list2[$k], 
    ];
}

echo json_encode($words);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the comma at the end of `$list2[$k]`. Then it worked perfectly. Thanks again